# Separating halves of a PairedBarChart

Tags: charts

**Question 1**:  How can I separate the halves of a `PairedBarChart` so as to create enough room for long labels, as in this example?

```
PairedBarChart[{3, 4, 6, 25, 4}, {1, 5, 5, 22, 3},
 ChartLabels -> {"Long label 1", "Long label 2", "Long label 3", "Long label 4", "Long label 5"},
 BarSpacing -> {0, .5},
 AxesLabel -> {Text[
    Style["Headcount", FontFamily -> "Times", 14, Italic]], 
   Text[Style["Function", FontFamily -> "Times", 18, Italic, Black]]}]
```

**Question 2**:  How can I label the horizontal axes differently, so on the left I have "Headcount A" and on the right "Headcount B"?

Of course, one could kludge together two separate `BarCharts` using `Row` and such, but that brings up scaling and alignment problems.  I'd like to achieve these within `PairedBarChart`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** `BarSpacing` takes a three-value form in this case:

> With the setting `BarSpacing->{$s_p$, $s_g$, $s_b$}, $s_p$ can be used to control the **space between the pair of bar charts**. The unit for $s_p$ is in fractions of the width of the resulting graphic.

```
chart = 
  PairedBarChart[
   {3, 4, 6, 25, 4}, {1, 5, 5, 22, 3},
   ChartLabels -> {"Long label 1", "Long label 2", 
                     "Long label 3", "Long label 4", "Long label 5"},
   BarSpacing -> {35, 0, .5},
   AxesLabel -> {
     Text[Style["Headcount", FontFamily -> "Times", 14, Italic]],
     Text[Style["Function", FontFamily -> "Times", 18, Italic, Black]]}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Question 2:** I found no direct method through options of PairedBarChart. A slightly kludgy workaround is to replace the first occurrence of the formatted label. Below is a helper function to do that replacement. We first find the first occurrence of the $x$-axis label to replace with `FirstPosition` then replace it with `MapAt`.

```
Clear[replaceAxis]
replaceAxis[chart_, rule_, addopts___] :=
 MapAt[
   # /. f_@Style[First@rule, opts___] :> f@Style[Last@rule, opts, addopts] &,
   chart,
   FirstPosition[chart, f_[Style[First@rule, ___]]]
 ]
```

Here is a usage example on the `chart` generated above:

```
replaceAxis[chart, "Headcount" -> "NewLabel"]
```

[image: relabeled]

This also allows to change the `Style` options for the new label after the chart has been generated. For instance:

```
replaceAxis[chart, "Headcount" -> "RedLabel", Red, 18]
```

[image: with larger red label]

Comment: Thanks so much.  I didn't see that third option in my cursory view of the documentation.  Any hints on my second question?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I put a helper function together to change one of the two labels (see edited answer). It is not a solution within `PairedBarChart`, but it should be reasonably effective nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks.  That works (accept).  (Wolfram should adopt your hack!)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Glad you like it! It may still be a bit brittle, but it should work in a pinch!